# Запуск приложений с установкой темы (GTK_THEME)

Tags: linux, gtk, fedora, gnome

Прочитал, что можно перед запуском приложения написать

```
GTK_THEME=<theme name> leafpad
```

И приложения leafpad запустится з нужной темой, отличной от дефаултной в системе. Вопрос в том, как получить список доступных тем? Например, в одном из примеров было указано такое:

```
GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark leafpad
```

Но как узнать, что именно Adwaita:dark а не Adwaita_dark или Adwaita-dark
Для приведённого примера работает, но, например, с темой Adapta не знаю, как правильно.

https://github.com/adapta-project/adapta-gtk-theme

Comment: Я попробовал этот трюк на xubuntu - не работает. Возможно, это только для гнома 3... Но, в теории, у xfce имеется полная поддержка gtk 3. В общем, странный какой-то костыль.

Comment: Странность в том, что работает только для Adwaita:dark для других или не работает, или я не правильно указываю имя темы. В этом и вопрос.

Comment: `ls -d /usr/share/themes/*/gtk*` не пойдёт? вероятно есть и другие каталоги. полный список где-то в недрах доков/исходников gtk. само собой, внимание на версию gtk.

Comment: Вряд ли. Тема устанавливается "Adwaita:dark"  но каталог называется Adwaita-dark. Т.е они не идентичны.

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor, очевидно, что они взаимозаменяемы...

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor Я немного о другом - в xubuntu имеется тема adwaita-dark, но этот трюк всё равно не работает. И с другими темами пробовал, тоже не получилось.